# How to remove style content of button on click

Tags: jquery, css

Ok so I'm trying to make it so that whenever you click on this button it removes the style content contained within it.

```
<button id="margin" onclick="save()" class="submit" type="submit">

  <style>
    .enable {
      margin-bottom:420px;
    }
  </style>

</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will remove the **HTML** contents of button **#margin** when clicked.

```
$("#margin").on("click", function(){
 $(this).html('');
});
```

and If you are trying to remove the **CSS margin-bottom** property from the `.enable` element, use :

```
$("#margin").on("click", function(){
 $(".enable").css("margin-bottom", "0px");
});
```

Replace `0px` in above code to the original **margin bottom** of `.enable`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#margin").on("click", function(){
 $(this).html('');// $(this).text(''); //$(this).empty(); //$(this).find('*').remove();
});
```

---

If you want remove style from elements

```
$(".enable").css("margin-bottom", "0px");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#margin").click(function() {
    $(this).html("");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9HBe4/ (embellishes css rules and html to demonstrate the method)

```
// listen for click event on target element
$("#margin").on("click", function(){
    // select `style` tag within `this` element, and remove it
    $("style", this).remove();
});
```

Comment: @leblma haha, he just edited the OP's question, he's not the asker, remove your downvote if you had casted any.

Comment: There is no pleasing some people :)